What game features a battle against a giant gold/bronze man?
I stumbled upon this image on Instagram. I assume it's from the PS2 era?

Description: A giant gold/bronze man with glowing blue eyes slams his hand down, hitting the playable character and making him splatter blood.

That is God of War 2 for the PS2. Here is a more clear screenshot, taken from the same battle against the Colossus of Rhodes boss.

Source

I really miss the dark, hazy blue atmosphere that a lot of games from that era had...

@N00B_141 It's often distance fog to hide the short draw distance.

And an abundance of bloom! For a long time, bloom was realism.
